# Not all events firing on button clicks

Tags: javascript, onclick, google-visualization, getjson, pie-chart

EDIT:
I have fixed the code so that the callback calls `drawChart` outside of the function, and it does in fact work on a button click. But, I have two things happening that need to happen on one button click.

I am using `$.get` to grab data that I have loaded into an array server-side (nodejs) and then send the response of this data to the pie chart. I am not getting any errors inside my command prompt or on the console inside the browser, so I am at a loss as to why both `.click` actions are not firing.

At first, the pie chart was not working, but then I adjusted it to have the chart draw at the correct time on the button click and now the chart works, but not the other action.

Also, is it not possible to have more than one `$.get` request on a button click? I do not have it fully implemented in below code, but I am ultimately trying to do that.
(on first request, I send an array of tweets to the clientside javascript to parse, on second request I send an array of other analyzation data to the clientside javascript to put into the piechart visualization)

Here is some code:

```
$("#startButton").click(function() {
    $.get( "/startButton", success);
    function success(data){ ... code inside creates html for 2 divs..., has been working }
});

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    //chartData);
    [
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);
    var options = {
        title: 'Retweets versus Original Tweets'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
function initialize() {
    $('#startButton').click(function() {
        drawChart();
    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
```

Comment: Which click event isn't working?  You should be able to assign an arbitrarily large number of functions as click event handlers (any of which may include as many AJAX requests as you would like), the only practical limitation being performance issues.

Comment: The click event involving the $.get with the start button is not working.

Comment: Try moving that to your `initialize` function or a document ready event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Function `drawChart()` is not called at all. This should work:

```
//    $(document).ready(function() {

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    //chartData);
    [
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);
    var options = {
      title: 'Retweets versus Original Tweets'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

//});
```

Comment: Wow, what a typical stupid mistake to make when coding. Just didn't even see that it was called before the function close. Thanks so much.

Comment: I am actually having more trouble than originally stated. I am going to edit the original post as an update on the bottom.